# Discord.py Reaction Roles and DMing the reactor

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want that the bot to give a role to the person who reacted to the message. The bot should also dm the person who had reacted. Thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    
    if payload.emoji.name == "" and payload.user_id != client.user.id:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description = "**You are now a Member of Resellheads!** ",
            color=16769251)
        
        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        
        await message.channel.send("<@&776929011757613057> Please add the role 'Member'!")
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't well fit for a question on SO. Try to search online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to react to a specific message (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926093/how-to-react-to-a-specific-message-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need to use raw reaction add in your case, as you are only using it to send a command.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    
    if reaction.emoji == '':
        await user.send("You are now a member of your community!")

    if reaction.emoji == '':
        await user.send("Sad to see you leave")
```

This will simply send any user who reacts with a thumbs up or down your command/message.

In this case, if your bot is a private or small bot this should be fine to use, but getting larger and in more servers, you should use a reaction wait that waits for he specified reaction after the author sent the command. There wasn’t much detail explained in your question but I hope this helps